# Space Characters Getting Converted to Unknown Character

Tags: regex, drupal, character-encoding, preg-match, space

I've got a problem with a module that I am writing. What I have is an array of names, which has a particular format and can contain characters as well as spaces. The name can be of two formats:

```
$name[0] = "--> Psychic Barrtier";
$name[1] ="    Initial Presence";
```

In my code, I take each line in the array, and use a preg_match statement to see if it matches these two patterns. So, I am basically looking for a line that starts with two dashes and '>' this, followed by a space. Or I am looking for a line that starts with 4 spaces. This is my preg_match statement:

```
while (preg_match('/^(--> |--&amp;gt; |--&gt; | {4}|&#160;&#160;&#160; |Â+)(.+)$/', $name[$i], $capturedname))
```

The problem is, both types of names are passing the preg_match statement, but when I encounter a name that starts with just the 4 spaces, the captured data in the variable $capturedname doesn't match up. Basically, what I'm capturing in $caputredname[0] is the whole thing, then $capturedname[1] would be just the spaces, and $capturedname[2] would be just the name. This is what I get instead:

$capturedname[0]=" Evil Presence"
$capturedname[1] = "�"
$capturedname[2] = "� Evil Presence"

Array 1 plus 2 should equal Array 0, but that's not the case here. The spaces are getting converted to some diamond with a question mark character and $capturedname[2] has the spaces again, it just doesn't add up. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. It's been bugging me for 3 days now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it's a conversion issue. Are you sure you don't have any formatting/other exotic characters in your input strings?

I have just done a quick test based on your array and pattern (though I'm not sure what that 'Â+' is meant to do there? Unless you expect such exotic strings...) and it worked pretty well for me:

```
$name = array(
  "--> Psychic Barrtier",
  "    Initial Presence",
);
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
  preg_match('/^(--> |--&amp;gt; |--&gt; | {4}|&#160;&#160;&#160; |Â+)(.+)$/', $value, $capturedname);
  print_r($capturedname);
}
```

which gave me following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => --> Psychic Barrtier
    [1] => --> 
    [2] => Psychic Barrtier
)
Array
(
    [0] =>     Initial Presence
    [1] =>     
    [2] => Initial Presence
)
```

So I think first I would check whether your input strings are really what you expect them to be...

Comment: The thing is, this is a Drupal module and the user enters this text in a text editor (Wymeditor) and has the HTML Purifier filter on.  Just as you said, I get it to work absolutely fine when the Purifier filter is OFF.

Comment: But when it is on, the '4 spaces + a word' string doesn't pass the preg_match, however, the one with the 'arrow + word' does. So, that's where the 'Â+' comes in, when I added that to my preg_match, the '4 spaces + a word' string finally passed the preg_match test with the Purifier filter ON.  It probably converts each space into an 'Â', that was my logic. However, now, I get this unmatched array problem and the unknown character.

Comment: Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to pass it through strtr() function first to replace all those Â (or any other strange chars) before passing your string to preg_match?